# How to write a sql query to Sort or Group the dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have data in a **table A** as shown below.   I want to group memberID  as one set and sort the Date_Time in each set as shown in snapshot below

```
Date_Time        PersonID     Status
4/2/14 10:15 AM    ghi        Closed
4/1/14 9:15 AM     ghi        Cancelled
4/1/14 11:00 AM    abc        Cancelled
4/2/14 8:12 AM     def        Closed
4/1/14 9:17 AM     def        Hold
4/3/14 2:17 PM     abc        Hold
4/2/14 8:30 AM     abc        Open
4/3/14 8:16 AM     jkl        Closed
4/1/14 12:10 PM    jkl        Open
4/1/14 11:30 AM    abc        Hold
```

The final example-snapshot attached below you will see **memberID: *ghi***  first row **date time *‘4/1/2014  9:15:00 AM’*** is greater than **memberID: *def***  1st row **date_Time *‘4/1/2014  9:17:00 AM’*** highlighted in yellow.  And that is the main reason **memberID  *ghi*** set  tweaks  as first set and then follows by **memberID *def*** set and then **meberID *abc*, *jkl* …** etc...

[image]

Could some one please help me how to write MS-SQL query to achieve the final result.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: ORDER BY date_time, person_id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to `join` the table back to itself using the `min` aggregate to establish a sort order:

```
select t.*
from yourtable t
  join (
    select personid, 
      min(date_time) min_date_time
    from yourtable
    group by personid
    ) t2 on t.personid = t2.personid
order by t2.min_date_time, t.date_time
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/144b8/3)

Comment: Yes @sgeddes you are absolutely correct.  Thank you so much for quick solution you suggested.  It is very simple and works fantastically Quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [another way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0717/1):

```
SELECT
  Date_Time,
  PersonID,
  Status
FROM
  dbo.atable
ORDER BY
  MIN(Date_Time) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID),
  PersonID,
  Date_Time
;
```

The approach, though, is same as in [sgeddes's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23925821/297408), it just has different syntax. It calculates minimum `Date_Time` values using `MIN(...) OVER (...)`. That makes a join to a derived table completely unnecessary.

One other little difference is that I have added `PersonID` to the ORDER BY clause to make sure that people with identical minimum `Date_Time` values do not have their rows mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `Order By PersonID, Date_Time` in the end of your select statement ?

Please note that sorting the `Date_Time` column will not work for you as expected if it is a string and not a `Date` field.

Provide a code sample of what you did so far so that we will be able to understand your problem more clearly so that we cab help you more efficiently.

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT Date_Time,PersonID,[Status] 
    FROM TABLE1
    GROUP BY Date_Time,PersonID,[Status] 
    ORDER BY PersonID,Date_Time
```

Comment: Your select statement **won't run successfully**; if you used a group by you need to use an aggregate function for the other columns that are not in the group by section **example:** `SELECT DATE_TIME, PERSONID, COUNT(STATUS) From... etc `

Comment: @sgeddes in the example in the link you provided, you can see that all the columns in the `Select` part exists in the `Group by` part.

Comment: @simsim -- now I see what you're saying -- you are absolutely correct.  This doesn't include `Status`.  Apologies.